# Is it legal to have duplicate enum values in C?

Tags: c, enums

```
enum protocol {
    ascii_prot = 3, /* arbitrary value. */
    binary_prot,
    negotiating_prot = 4 /* Discovering the protocol */
};
```

Both `binary_prot` and `negotiating_prot` equals to `4`?

Comment: It is **explicitly allowed** by the [N1265 C99 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) at 6.7.2.2/3 "Enumeration specifiers": "The use of enumerators with `=` may produce enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the same enumeration.". I had put this in an answer but http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297 deleted it because of duplicate answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30916409/895245 I don't think those questions are duplicates.

Comment: Hmmm, on second thought, maybe they should be marked as duplicates.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes.

Answer (score 6):

Yes; C is not particular about enum values.  Why you might do that is another question, unless there's some reason to treat the discovery packet the same as data packets.  (Which there might well be when someone else designed the protocol and you want to stick as closely as possible to their documentation.)