# Having duplicate enumerator values

Tags: c++, enums

I'm creating a Tetris clone in C++, and I have an enum `GameProperty`, which is specified as follows:

```
enum GameProperty {
    NUM_OF_TETROMINOES  = 7,
    NUM_OF_TILES        = 4,
    TETROMINO_ROTATIONS = 4
};
```

In my case, I **only** use these values when looping through a tetromino's tiles, e.g:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TETROMINO_TILES; i++) { }
```

Is it under any circumstance considered bad practice to have multiple enumerators with the same value?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561142/duplicate-enum-values-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These should not be values in a single `enum`. They should be separate constants. To see why, look at code like `i < TETROMINO_TILES`. The compares an `integer` to a `GameProperty` which can have values like `TETROMINO_ROTATIONS`. That makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enum` when you want to create a new, distinct type which *isn't* really a scalar value. For example, **colors** can be enumerated, and hence numbered, but those numbers don't really mean anything.

If you're assigning meaningful numbers to the enumerators, it's a sign that you might really want something like this:

```
namespace GameProperty { // completely different concepts with unifying theme
    int const num_tetrominoes  = 7,
              num_tiles        = 4,
              num_rotations    = 4;
};
```

Now you can use the same syntax, as well as `using` declarations, and these constants work in `for` loops and expressions with no conversion.

For another example, the following are both correct but shouldn't be swapped between `enum` and `int`:

```
namespace wavelengths { // closely related quantities
    typedef int wavelength_t; // maybe we will express in-between values
    wavelength_t const red    = 750,
                       green  = 550,
                       blue   = 400;
};

enum colors { // qualitatively different but related as one-of-many
    red,
    green,
    blue;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a enum just like you define a class. It should conceptually be a collection of values for ONE property, instead of multiple properties rigged up.